# Jar got copied twice while creating war file from ANT

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am newbie to ANT and trying a simple ANT script to create `.war` file of my project.
Here is my script
When I run this script everything works fine but `.jar` file present in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` are copied twice inside the `.war` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="AutoComplete">
     <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" >
        <javac includeantruntime="false" destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src" >
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="build.war" depends="compile">
        <war destfile="AutoComplete.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
            <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Please let me know if I am making any blunder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `build.war` task looks to be the culprit:

```
    <war destfile="AutoComplete.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <classes dir="build/classes"/>
    </war>
```

The first nested `<fileset>` pulls in all the files from `WebContent` to the root of the WAR.  The second line then explicitly says that everything in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` should be considered a library (and thus copied to `WEB-INF/lib` inside the WAR).

Deleting one of these lines should mean that the libs get copied once - if you do want everything inside WebContent to be copied as-is within the WAR, you can just delete the `<lib>` line.

Comment: Did the trick for me as well. Thanks for the concise explanation!